# How To add JavaScript function for a user control in ASP.net that can be called using control ID

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to create a simple user control that supports its own javascript functions to be called using control id , for example if I have the following control :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MyControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function controlClicked(ID) {
      alert('Hello I am Control:'+ID);
  }
</script>
```

I want to be able to do the following on the page that contains the user control

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Light.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="Control.Main" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls.MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyControl" %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function btnClicked() {
            myControl.controlClicked('myControl');
            }
        </script>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
          <uc1:MyControl runat="server" id="myControl" />

    <asp:Button id="Button1"
               Text="Call UserControl Function"
               onclientclick="btnClicked" 
               runat="server"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organized way is to use javascript prototype feature here.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MyControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var <%=this.ClientID%> = 
    {
        controlLoaded: function(ID) {
            alert('Hello I am Loaded:'+ID);
        },
        controlClicked: function(ID) {
            alert('Hello I am Clicked:'+ID);
        }
    }
</script>
```

"<%=this.ClientID%>" will generate a javascript prototype object for each occurrence of "MyControl" on the page. you can then use this prototype object to call methods for specific occurrence of the control. This can be done as given below:

```
<uc1:MyControl runat="server" id="myControl1" />

<button id="btnShowAlert1" onclick="javascript:btnShowAlert1_Clicked();">Click 1 </button>

<uc1:MyControl runat="server" id="myControl2" />

<button id="btnShowAlert2" onclick="javascript:btnShowAlert2_Clicked();">Click 2</button>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myControl1 = <%=myControl1.ClientID%>;
    var myControl2 = <%=myControl2.ClientID%>;

    function btnShowAlert1_Clicked() {
        if(typeof(myControl1) != "undefined") {
            myControl1.controlClicked('myControl1');
        }
    }

    function btnShowAlert2_Clicked() {
        if(typeof(myControl2) != "undefined") {
            myControl2.controlClicked('myControl2');
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        if(typeof(myControl1) != "undefined") {
            myControl1.controlLoaded('myControl1');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure every JavaScript function has a unique name. For that you can use `UniqueID`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function controlClicked_<%= UniqueID %>(ID) {
        alert('Hello I am Control:' + ID);
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Call UserControl Function" runat="server" />
```

And then set the `OnClientClick` in the code behind of the UserControl to match the corresponding JavaScript function.

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "controlClicked_" + UniqueID;
```